# How to add a marker to Mapbox on click event?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm a french student in computering and I have to use Mapbox but since I create a class I'm stuck by this error.When I wasn't in a class it worked perfectly but now it's fully broken.And I saw on some topics it could come from safari but I already tested it on Mozilla and it still broken.

This is my class.

```
  constructor() {
    //Temporary array of currentMarkers
    let currentMarkers=[];
    let type ="";
    //Create the map
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'private data';
    this.mapbox = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position
      zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });

    //Add search bar from a plugin
    let geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      placeholder: 'Saissisez une adresse', // Placeholder text for the search bar
      marker: {
        color: 'orange'
      },
      mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    });

    this.mapbox.addControl(geocoder);

    const mbox = this;

    this.mapbox.on("click",function(){
      this.getcoordonates();
    });


    //Allow us to create marker just with a research
    geocoder.on('result', function(e) {
      //Deleting all current markers
      if (currentMarkers!==null) {
        for (let i = currentMarkers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          currentMarkers[i].remove();
        }
      }
      //Add the markers who come with the research
      this.addMarker(e.result.center[0],e.result.center[1]);

      // Delete the last marker who got placed
      //currentMarkers[currentMarkers.length - 1].remove();
    });

      this.addPoint(2.333333 ,48.866667 ,"supervisor");
  }





  //split the JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap()) to get the coordinates
  async mysplit(m){
    let z = m.split(',');
    let x = z[0].replace("{\"lng\":","");
    let g = z[1].replace("\"lat\":","");
    let y = g.replace("}","");
    await addMarker(x,y);
  }


  //Add a marker on click after the excution of mysplit() function
  async addMarker(x,y) {
    // tmp marker
    let oneMarker= new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([x,y])
    .addTo(this.mbox);
    currentMarkers.push(oneMarker);
  }



  // Get the coordinates and send it to split function
  getcoordonates(){
      mbox.on('click',function(e){
    let m = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap());
    this.mbox.mysplit(m);
  });
}

addPoint(y,x,type)
{
  let color ="";
  let t = type;

  if(t == "supervisor")
  {
    color = "grey";

  }else if (t =="fieldworker") {
    color = "red";
  }else if (t == "intervention") {
    color = "blue";
  }else alert("Nous ne pouvons pas ajouter votre marker\nLatitude : "+x+"\nLongitude :"+y+"\n car "+t+" n'est pas un type reconnu" );

  let myMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker({"color": color})
  .setLngLat([y,x])
  .addTo(this.mbox);
}





}
```

Thanks for help and have a good day :) ! Sorry if my English isn't that good.

Comment: The `this.mapbox.on(...)` call is outside of the constructor. Make sure you use a code editor or IDE smart enough to highlight these syntax errors in real time.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm using ATOM as IDE I'm going to add package that highlight syntax errors. Now I got that error "TypeError: this.getcoordonates is not a function. (In 'this.getcoordonates()', 'this.getcoordonates' is undefined)" and I already have it but I don't really understand because my function is declared in my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first step, the

```
   this.mapbox.on("click", function(e){
     this.getcoordonates();
   });
```

was called outside of any method of the `Map` class. It would most probably belong to the constructor (as discussed above in the question's comments section).

---

Next, the callback changes the scope of `this`, so it is not anymore pointing to a `Map` instance. A common solution to this issue is to store/backup `this` before, something like:

```
constructor() {
  ...
  const thisObject = this;
  this.mapbox.on("click", function(e) {
    thisObject.getcoordonates();
  });
}
```

**Update:**
The logic of code in its current form tries to add a new click event listener every time the map is clicked. Which is not desired. This `getcoordonates()` function is not really needed. Instead this should work (never tested it, it is based on your code):

```
constructor() {
  ...
  const mbox = this;
  this.mapbox.on("click", function(e) {
    let m = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap());
    mbox.mysplit(m);
  });
}
```

Remarks:

- There is no real logic behind JSON-encoding the lngLat object before calling `mysplit` just to decode it there.
- You won't need it here, but the reverse of the `JSON.stringify()` is `JSON.parse()`. There is no need to work with it on a string level, like the current `mysplit()` method does.
- Instead, the `mysplit()` method should be called directly with the `e.lngLat` object as its argument.
- Going further, since there is no "splitting" (decoding) really needed, the `mysplit()` method isn't really needed either.

In the end, something like this should work:

```
constructor() {
  ...
  const mbox = this;
  this.mapbox.on("click", function(e) {
    await mbox.addMarker(e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat);
  });
}
```

Comment: So my function getcoordonates is using another function  but it still saying that my variable isn't existing so I think it's basically like c# and I need an accessor ? (Sorry for all those question but it's my first time with js object so I want be sure of what I'm doing to not do errors like that again.)

Comment: Indeed, the `map` variable used in `getcoordonates()` doesn't seem to be initialized. Where should it come from?

Comment: Also, I am not sure about the contents of `getcoordonates()`. Are you sure you want to assign a new `click` event listener every time `this.mapbox` is clicked?

Comment: Above you can see my actual class I just updated the topic.I don't want to create a new event click every time my map is clicked I want to create a marker each you clicked on the map but I looked on Mapbox topic and I followed their instruction.And my error is that mbox doesn't exist out of the constructor